# How to use maxout activation function in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use maxout activation function in tensorflow, but I don't know which function should use.

Answer (score 5):

I sent a pull request for maxout, here is the link:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/5528

Code is as follows:

```
def maxout(inputs, num_units, axis=None):
    shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
    if axis is None:
        # Assume that channel is the last dimension
        axis = -1
    num_channels = shape[axis]
    if num_channels % num_units:
        raise ValueError('number of features({}) is not a multiple of num_units({})'
             .format(num_channels, num_units))
    shape[axis] = -1
    shape += [num_channels // num_units]
    outputs = tf.reduce_max(tf.reshape(inputs, shape), -1, keep_dims=False)
    return outputs
```

Here is how it works:

[image: github screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a maxout activation but there is nothing stopping yourself from making it yourself.  You could do something like the following.

```
with tf.variable_scope('maxout'):
  layer_input = ...
  layer_output = None
  for i in range(n_maxouts):
    W = tf.get_variable('W_%d' % d, (n_input, n_output))
    b = tf.get_variable('b_%d' % i, (n_output,))
    y = tf.matmul(layer_input, W) + b
    if layer_output is None:
      layer_output = y
    else:
      layer_output = tf.maximum(layer_output, y)
```

Note that this is code I just wrote in my browser so there may be syntax errors but you should get the general idea.  You simply perform a number of linear transforms and take the maximum across all the transforms.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?
This seems to work in my test.

```
def max_out(input_tensor,output_size):
shape = input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()
if shape[1] % output_size == 0:
    return tf.transpose(tf.reduce_max(tf.split(input_tensor,output_size,1),axis=2))
else:
    raise ValueError("Output size or input tensor size is not fine. Please check it. Reminder need be zero.")
```

I refer the diagram in [the following page](http://blog.yusugomori.com/post/133257383300/%E6%95%B0%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%A7%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%99-maxout-networks).

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.4 on you can use [tf.contrib.layers.maxout](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/maxout).

Answer (score 0):

Maxout is a layer such that it calculates N*M output for a N*1 input, and then it returns the maximum value across the column, i.e., the final output has shape N*1 as well. Basically it uses multiple linear fittings to mimic a complex function.